# jQuery mobile 1.1.0: strange 'pagebeforechange' behavior

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got big HTML page with "`divs`" that are considered "pages" and, I'm swapping between those "`divs`".

I've added this code:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
        console.log(data.toPage);
    }
}
```

And here's the console log:

```
#page-main
http://ba.m.p.fr/#page-panier
http://ba.m.p.fr/#page-horaires
http://ba.m.p.fr/#page-horaires&ui-page=1-5
http://ba.m.p.fr/#page-horaire-valider
```

So, sometimes it's only the `id` sometimes it's the whole URL. How comes?

Comment: How do you do to swap between those pages? Do you use the changePage method, links or both?

Comment: I'm using only `changePage` method

Comment: So when are you getting the first value, just with the id? According to jQuery Mobile docs "The value (toPage) exactly matches the 1st arg to the changePage() call that triggered the event"

Comment: In the log you can read `&ui-page=1-5` which means it's jQuery itself that has made this link (see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-ul.html). This means that sometimes, even jQuery Mobile itself makes full URL links, which, I'm pretty sure, wasn't the case before, because my app wouldn't have worked for a long long time.

Comment: I found out a workaround (see my own answer). It's better, cleaner, and safer in the long run to use `on()` and the `pagebeforeshow` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a workaround, this is not an explanation. My old code was like:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
        if (data.toPage == "page-aa" ) {
            /* code for page-aa */
        } else if (data.toPage === "page-bb" ) {
            /* code for page-bb */
        } else if (data.toPage === "page-cc" ) {
            /* code for page-cc */
        }
    }
}
```

And now my new code is like this: i'm relying on '`pagebeforeshow`':

```
$("div#page-aa").on('pagebeforeshow', function(e, data) {
    /* code for page-aa */
});
$("div#page-bb").on('pagebeforeshow', function(e, data) {
    /* code for page-bb */
});
$("div#page-cc").on('pagebeforeshow', function(e, data) {
    /* code for page-cc */
});
```

And it works flawlessly. But this is a workaround, not an explanation of my question. Anyway if someone googles for that problem, and reads my question, maybe this workaround will help!

Answer (score 0):

toPage can be either a jQuery collection object containing the page to be transitioned to, OR a URL reference for a page to be loaded/transitioned to.

```
// We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
// asking us to load a page by URL.
if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) ...
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html